# Correcting in page navigation position when using fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a fixed navbar with bootstrap 4. When using `fixed-top` navbar, content below it is hidden by the navbar because its position is fixed. I had to give `padding-top: 65px;` on the body, to make the content appear below the navbar.

I have internal links so clicking on a navbar anchor positions the page on the section relative to it. However, because I used the `padding-top` trick, the position is 65px below the top of the section. Is there a way to solve it so that position returns to the top of the section?

Comment: Since you want sticky navbar, it will act as fixed div, so you must give padding-top to that div. You can give that padding-top dynamically using jquery also, please let me know if you want to get it done by jquery.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @KunalKhatri I don't mind solving this is jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of a link, I set the padding top of the body to 0, and on hash change event after the page positions on the section relative to the inline link, I set back the padding to 65.

```
$('.nav-link').click(function () {
        $('body').css('padding-top', '0');
});


window.onhashchange = function () {
    $('body').css('padding-top', '65px');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add from the first " fixed-nav" class. you can add this in scroll event of jquery.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

var scrollTop = 20;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop) {
        $('nav').addClass("fixed-nav");

    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop) {
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');

    }
});
```

this add fixed-nav in user scroll down in your site.

Comment: Using this code, this will suddenly make navbar sticky, so it will not work on scroll to, content will go behind the navbar.

Comment: if you don't want be suddenly, just add transition: 0.2s all; this code work in scroll and actually in sticky nav after scroll yes, content will go behind the navbar. for good view use background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); transparent background. like http://abron.co

Comment: @HamidNaghipour in my situation the navbar is positioned on the top as the first element of the page, this is why I set it fixed by default and want it to remain fixed. The solution you provided does not solve the problem I mentioned neither the way it works on abron.co. Look on abron.co when you click on a nav link how the page scrolls to a position below the top of the relative section and not to the top of the section. What I want is to make it scroll to the top of the section.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var top_pad = $('.your_headerelem').height();
    $('.first-emem-after-header').css({'padding-top':+top_pad+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var top_pad = $('.your_headerelem').height();
        $('.first-emem-after-header').css({'padding-top':top_pad+'px'});
   }) ;
}) ;
```

This will make your first element after header, lie below header.

Comment: your are giving me solution to make the navbar fixed, something I already have working. My problem is positioning the page after clicking on one of the nav links. When I click on an nav link now, the page scrolls to the relative section but scrolls in addition: the height of the navbar (top + 65px because the navbar height is 65px). I want it to scroll only to the top of the section.